# Logging into website using C# HttpWebRequests, then opening in browser

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, web, httprequest

I want to automate the logging in process for a website.

The login process takes multiple requests to gather cookies and set form values based on those cookies. Using a few C# HttpWebRequests, I have gotten it where the last HttpWebResponse returns the data I want, indicating I have successfully authenticated.

Is it possible to open this session in a browser so that I will be logged in when the page opens? I'm beginning to think its not since my session is tied to a JSESSIONID cookie and there's no way that I know of to manually set that in a browser.

Thanks.

Comment: Firefox enables you to edit HTTP Request Headers, so technically you could manually add in the session cookie values using Firefox Dev Tools then send the edited HTTP Request. Is your intent to simply experiment with HTTP Headers?

Comment: I have my HTTP Requests working perfectly. I can return an authenticated page in my HTTP response (I can see things like my username and "Sign out" in the response stream). I want to be able to open this authenticated page in a browser rather than viewing its html in a HttpWebResponse stream.

Comment: Then you'll need to manually add the session cookies and etc to your browser's HTTP Request. I don't believe you can do that directly in code, but you can use Firefox's Developer Tools to accomplish this pretty easily. You should theoretically be able to "hijack" the session established by your C# application this way.

Comment: As an additional note, browsers internally manage cookies that have been set for a domain and keep track of when to add cookies in a HTTP Request based on the domain being accessed. The latest versions of popular web browsers tend to prevent the injection of cookies inside their own internal management systems if they aren't properly set by a HTTP Response. Therefore, I don't know of a non-hacky way your C# code can directly set a cookie in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide an answer:

Cookies are passed to web servers via a HTTP Header. Browsers internally manage cookies that have been set for a domain and keep track of when to add cookies in a HTTP Request based on the domain being accessed. The latest versions of popular web browsers tend to prevent the injection of cookies inside their own internal management systems if they aren't properly set by a HTTP Response. Therefore, I don't know of a non-hacky way your C# code can directly set a cookie in your browser.

However,

You can try manually adding the session cookies and etc to your browser's HTTP Request (it would be a neat experiment and should actually work). You can use Firefox's Developer Tools to accomplish this pretty easily. You should theoretically be able to "hijack" the session established by your C# application this way.

You could also just maintain the session through your HttpWebResponse stream, but I unless you're developing a web browser then it won't be easy to interpret the markup visually.